# Multiple rules of htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use an htaccess file with 2 rules. The first one is working, but the second displays a white page with the URL in browser correct. If I delete first, rule the second one works. I don't know how to make it work with more than one rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /display.php?fly_id=$1
```

Comment: What do you want `/somestring` to rewrite to? How is it supposed to choose between them, when the use they same regex.

Comment: I am a beginner in this stuff and I don't know how to make them work separately.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: We still need to know what you want... WHen the url is `/monkey` what rewrite rule do you want to use?